# What is best practice for initialization of global variables in Swift?

Tags: swift, global-variables

When declaring global variables, where is the "best practice" place to initialize them in the code?

I have a button that I would like to declare as a constant but in doing so would have to initialize it at the top of the code file, which I've been taught and seen isn't the best option.

I'm having a hard time reconciling putting something like this in a global scope.

```
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,64,49))
```

One option would be to change it to a var and just reinitialize like this:

```
var button = UIButton()
```

Then later in a given function do:

```
button = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,64,49))
```

but this seems like a waste initializing twice.

Thoughts?

Comment: I can't imagine why you would need a global button object.  I think you're asking the wrong question--worrying about the wrong problem.  You're worrying about "best practice" with a global button variable, when best practice almost certainly says don't have a global button at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can declare it as optional:

```
var button: UIButton?
```

and initialize it later:

```
button = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,64,49))
```